# I'm using python, and I work with SELECT and UPDATE statement in a single cursor for the same table

Tags: python, mysql, database, connection, cursor

Here is the code that I try to run

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',
                                     database="database",
                                     user="user",
                                     password="password")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  admin = 'true'")
dict_result = cursor.fetchone()
while dict_result is not None:
    print(dict_result)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE employee SET salary = 10000 WHERE uuid = '%s'" % (dict_result[0]))
    dict_result = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.close()
```

Error achieved by above:
But i got 'unread result found' error

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error where i had to commit after the fetch to make sure that all of the results was gathered as the `fetch` call is asynchronous.

My fix was to add:

```
connection.commit()
```

After the fetch but before the close.

Ex:

```
connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='host',
                                 database="database",
                                 user="user",
                                 password="password")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE  admin = 'true'")
dict_result = cursor.fetchone()
while dict_result is not None:
    print(dict_result)
    cursor.execute("UPDATE employee SET salary = 10000 WHERE uuid = '%s'" % (dict_result[0]))
    dict_result = cursor.fetchone()
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```